# jQuery validate won't submit after check

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to create a form that validates with the jQuery validate plugin.
I have successfully implemented Validation so it checks the areas of the form that I want it to but now the form won't submit once the form input areas are filled in. can someone please provide some advice as to how I might be able to make it submit once validated.

also not necessary but would be nice is I would like the error message label to appear to the right or bottom of the form areas. Here is my code, any advice would be appreciated PS I am quite a novice sorry for bad formatting.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-
methods.min.js"></script>

<!------- Web page Content ------>


            <div id="content">


        <h2> Register with GTB Financial Solutions  </h2>   

        <form method="post" action="post-test.php" id="myform" name="myform" onsubmit="return validate();">

        How to maximise profits on managed funds<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br>
        Minimising tax in the new environment<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br>
        Measuring stock momentum<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br>
        Economic forecasts<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br>
        Creative accounting for management<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br>
        The exciting new features of the ATO web site<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br><br>      
        <label for="Fname">First Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="Fname"  id="Fname"><br>
        <label for="Lname">Last Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="Lname"  id="Lname"><br>
        <label for="Phone">Phone Number</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="Phone"  id="Phone"><br>
        <label for="E-mail">E-mail Address</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email"  id="email"><br>
        <label for="Address">Address</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="Address"  id="Address"><br>



        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <script>

    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid",
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
       }
   });
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            chkbox: {
                required: true,
            },
            Fname: "required",
            Lname: "required",
            Phone: "required",  
            Address: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

        },
        messages: {
            Fname: "Please enter your firstname",
            Lname: "Please enter your lastname",
            Phone:  "Please enter your phone number",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"

        }
    });

</script>


            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php

Comment: An edit request would be better @mrid as the user is new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

By setting `debug : true` in `jQuery.validator.setDefaults` you are telling jquery validate plugin that you want to debug and do no wish to submit the form right now.

set `debug` as `false` instead.

Also remove `return validate()` from `onsumbit`

Comment: I have removed return validate() and set debug to false but it just provides me with the alert box on succesful validation and doesn't proceed to the action of the form post-test.php

Comment: Maybe there is some other error, open developer console by pressing f12 and check what error are yoi getting? I copy pasted your same code and did the following 2 steps above and it was redirecting then!

Comment: I couldn't figure out where to view the redirection to post-test.php in the developer tools however I adjusted the code. when i altered  
  submitHandler: function() {
    alert("submitted!");
    }

Comment: I couldn't figure out how I could view the redirection in developer tools. however I did adjust my code so I could be redirected on submission, I adjusted the submit handler from an alert to form.submit() the code was as follows  submitHandler: function() {
    form.submit();
  } instead of  submitHandler: function() {
    alert("submitted!");
  }

Answer (score 0):

Its working , Just remove `onsubmit="return validate();"` from form:

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid",
  submitHandler: function() {
    alert("submitted!");
  }
});
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    chkbox: {
      required: true,
    },
    Fname: "required",
    Lname: "required",
    Phone: "required",
    Address: "required",
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },

  },
  messages: {
    Fname: "Please enter your firstname",
    Lname: "Please enter your lastname",
    Phone: "Please enter your phone number",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address"

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-
methods.min.js"></script>

<!------- Web page Content ------>


<div id="content">


  <h2> Register with GTB Financial Solutions </h2>

  <form method="post" action="post-test.php" id="myform" name="myform" >

    How to maximise profits on managed funds<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br> Minimising tax in the new environment<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br> Measuring stock momentum<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br> Economic forecasts
    <input
      type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br> Creative accounting for management<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br> The exciting new features of the ATO web site<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"><br><br>
      <label for="Fname">First Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Fname" id="Fname"><br>
      <label for="Lname">Last Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Lname" id="Lname"><br>
      <label for="Phone">Phone Number</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone"><br>
      <label for="E-mail">E-mail Address</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
      <label for="Address">Address</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address"><br>

      <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

</div>
```